# Aurelia-i18n attribute [t] vs [i18n]

Tags: internationalization, aurelia

I was wondering what the difference between these two attributes is when using the "aurelia-i18n" plugin

They are both defined in my main.ts inside the i18n plugin "startup"

```
lng: "en",
attributes: ["t", "i18n"],
fallbackLng: "en",
```

However, the `i18n` attribute only seems to work in "Views" and doesn't work when used inside a custom element. However `t` does work in custom elements. I was wondering if there was some kind of difference between these two, that is not described [in the docs?](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/i18n/latest/i18n-with-aurelia/1)

Comment: this turns out to be a bug: filed here: https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/206

Answer (score 0):

True there is/was a bug filed for that but in the meantime got resolved with the latest release. An [accompanying issue](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/209) is this here, which is also documented with a recent docs update

No other differences should be present, and the sole purpose is to give developers the freedom to chose other aliases.